# Is it possible to have the same copula for two different joint distributions.

Tags: probability, distributions, copula

Say, I have two random variables $X$ & $Y$, whose CDF is $F(x,y)$. Similar, I have one more set of random variables $P$ & $Q$, whose CDF is $G(p,q)$. Is it possible that $F$ and $G$ have the same copula CDF $C(u,v)$, where $U$ & $V$ are uniformly distributed marginals? If so, can we say something about the relationship between $F$ and $G$.

Thank you.

My understanding:

It is possible to have $F$ and $G$, whose bivariate joint distributions may look different on the outside, but still have the same Copula CDF $C$

Comment: Since applying a definition of a copula provides a ready answer to this question, could you tell us what you understand a "copula" to be?

Comment: @whuber: I will give an example of my understanding - Say, we take a simple bivariate normal distribution. We do a non-linear transformation on both the axis. The resulting distribution is no-longer bi-variate normal. Neverthless, the original normal distribution and this distorted distribution are linked by the Gaussian Copula. Please correct me if I am wrong. I thought I will ask my actual question instead of posting parts of the bigger question.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348421/maximum-likelihood-estimation-of-a-gaussian-copula

Comment: Your answer answers your question: any transform that turns a real into a value on $(0,1)$ defines a copula. Hence missing unicity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The difference between joint distributions is due to the difference of marginal distributions. By Sklar's theorem, we have the relationship between $F$ and $G$:
$$
F(x,y) = C(F_X(x), F_Y(y)), ~ G(x,y) = C(F_P(x), F_Q(y)).
$$